# Pacemaker - inconsistent data bewteen crm_resource resource list and CIB content

Tags: high-availability

I added a resource and then deleted it afterwards.
However, when I issue the following command:

```
crm_resource -l
```

It is still listed! I try to remove it:

```
crm configure delete <resource_name>
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: object <resource_name> does not exist
```

Moreover:

```
crm configure show | grep <resource_name>
```

doesn't match any resource of that name! CIB also doesn't have it listed under LRM...

Any idea how to get rid of this resource?

Thanks,

D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be "normal" in Pacemaker 1.1.6 - if you tell it delete something, it will delete it and then complain to you that it no longer exists.